# How do I make the unique check on month of a year in Laravel

Tags: php, validation, date, laravel-5

Here is a table named `installments` which has `date_of_receipt` and `user_id` columns. I need to check if a date `date_of_receipt = 27-01-2019` has present according to a user so I have to validate this entity already exists here for any January 2019 day. How can I do that in Laravel5.7 with MySQL?

Comment: Is the field `date_of_receipt` a datetime?

Comment: Yes. This the date with `d-m-Y` format. This would be running date or may vary manually.

Comment: But how is it saved in your database? As a string or as a datetime?

Comment: Currently, I am using as string. If that gonna be `datetime`  or `date` there is no problem. But must be unique according to month and year. How?

Comment: I added an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are storing it as a string in a particular format, you could achieve this with something like this:

```
$start = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->date_of_receipt)->startOfMonth()->format('d-m-Y');
$end   = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->date_of_receipt)->endOfMonth()->endOfDay()->format('d-m-Y');

return DB::table('installments')
    ->where('user_id', $user_id)
    ->whereBetween('date_of_receipt', [$start, $end])
    ->exists();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering me. But this the solution only for January 2019. Actually this `$start` and `$end ` date varies according to `$request->date_of_receipt`. For example if the `$request->date_of_receipt` is `25-12-2018` so, here need to change the `$start` and `$end` regarding to `$request->date_of_receipt` date.

Comment: Edited my answer to cater for this. Let me know if it works out for you :)

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Thanks a million :)